# How to setup sub-domains for a new IP?

Tags: domain-name-system

Currently I have a domain `example.org` and one sub-domain `peter.example.org` hosting on one IP:

```
example.org

@        A       111.111.111.111
peter    CNAME   @
```

If I am going to add two sub-domain `paul.example.org` and `mary.example.org` for a new IP `222.222.222.222`, is it correct to set up as:

```
example.org

@        A       111.111.111.111
peter    CNAME   @
paul     A       222.222.222.222
mary     A       222.222.222.222
```

Comment: looks ok, but the mary one could also be a CNAME pointing at paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is OK.

Depending on your needs, you can setup paul or mary as a CNAME of the other.